# Groovy named parameters cause parameter assignments to switch--any way around this?

Tags: groovy, named-parameters

Groovy will collect all the named parameters into a map and pass it into a method as the first parameter.  This seems neat, but after trying to make it work it seems really unusable.

So the issue is a method like this:

```
def method(paramMap, specificVar1 = 7, specificVar2 = 14)
```

when you call this method with something like this:

```
method(12, extraValue: "hello")
```

you get pretty much what you expect:

```
assert 12 == specificVar1
assert 14 == specificVar2
assert [extraValue:"hello"] == paramMap
```

not bad, makes sense.  The problem is, if you assume the `Map` params are optional then you can end up with values like this:

```
method(12)
```

```
assert paramMap == 12
assert specificVar1 == 7 // default values
assert specificVar2 == 14
```

That scalar should have gone into specificVar--not the map.  If I specifically type the map in the method:

```
def method(Map paramMap, specificVar1 = 7, specificVar2 = 14)
```

then `method(12, extraValue: "hello")` works just as it did before, but `method(12)` throws a `ClassCastException`.  This just doesn't seem usable. Is there any way to make that `Map` "sticky" so that it will simply be empty if there are no `Map` parameters?

Note:

A decade later I revisited this because of a 2500 views notification. The accepted answers' overloading solution is perfect.  Basically a second method:

```
def method(specificVar1 = 7, specificVar2 = 14) 
{
    method([:],specificVar1, specificVar2)
}
```

seems to work perfectly for all my test cases, with or without defaults.

If I were to pursue this further, I might try to figure out how to synthetically generate an overload like this for a bunch of methods that I like to run from the repl.

Comment: Bill K, updated my answer with a very simple solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setting default values on parameters create overloaded methods with combinations made from left to right, thus, it is hard to make `method(12)` and also be able to pass map entries.

Your method `def method(paramMap, specificVar1=7, specificVar2=14)` will generate the following methods:

```
Object Maps.method(java.lang.Object)
Object Maps.method(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)
Object Maps.method(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)
```

And a fully typed method with the map param:

```
def method3(Map paramMap=[:], Integer specificVar1=7, Integer specificVar2=14) {
}
```

Will generate the following methods:

```
Object Maps.method3()
Object Maps.method3(java.util.Map)
Object Maps.method3(java.util.Map,java.lang.Integer)
Object Maps.method3(java.util.Map,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
```

(No suitable method for `method(12)`).

Also, entries passed to the method will be collected and inserted in the first *map* parameter. The following method:

```
def method4(Integer specificVar1=7, Integer specificVar2=14, Map map=[:]) {
```

Generates:

```
Object Maps.method4()
Object Maps.method4(java.lang.Integer)
Object Maps.method4(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
Object Maps.method4(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.util.Map)
```

Thus, `method4 12, a:'b'` fails with:

```
No signature of method: Maps.method4() is applicable for argument types: 
  (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.Integer) values: [[a:b], 12]
```

So, no, i don't think you can do what you want using maps :-).

---

**Solution 1:**

If you are in for a pure dynamic solution, you can use a single map argument:

```
def method5(Map map) {
  def specificVar1 = map.specificVar1 ?: 7
  def specificVar2 = map.specificVar2 ?: 14
}
```

**Solution 2 (updated):**

You can create a class to represent the parameters. Using a map to be coerced into the object is statically compilable and a syntatic sugar for it.

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class Maps {
  def method6(Foo foo) { "$foo.params, $foo.specificVar1, $foo.specificVar2" }
  def method6(Map map) { method6 map as Foo }

  static main(args) {
    def maps = new Maps()

    assert maps.method6(params: [a: 'b', c: 'd'], specificVar1: 40) ==
        "[a:b, c:d], 40, 14"

    assert maps.method6(new Foo(params: [a: 'b', c: 'd'], specificVar2: 21)) == 
        "[a:b, c:d], 7, 21"
  }
}

class Foo {
  def specificVar1 = 7, specificVar2 = 14, params = [:]
}
```

**Solution 3:**

An overloaded method.

```
def method6(Map paramMap, Integer specificVar1=7, Integer specificVar2=14) {
  "$paramMap, $specificVar1, $specificVar2"
}

def method6(Integer specificVar1=7, Integer specificVar2=14) {
  method6 [:], specificVar1, specificVar2
}


assert method6( 12 ) == "[:], 12, 14"
assert method6( ) == "[:], 7, 14"
assert method6( a:'b', 18 ) == "[a:b], 18, 14"
assert method6( 18, a:'b', 27 ) == "[a:b], 18, 27"
assert method6( 90, 100 ) == "[:], 90, 100"
assert method6( a:'b', 140, c:'d' ) == "[a:b, c:d], 140, 14"
```

The map version method can't have a default parameter, otherwise both methods will generate a parameterless `method6` and those will conflict.

Comment: Good analysis.  I'm leaning towards the single map solution, but it makes using it a little tougher (Type safety, easy at-a-glance parameter list...), but it may be the best we can do in the current groovy

Comment: That's fantastic.  I love Solution 3!  Thank you very much for your time and persistence @Will.  I bet there is a way to generate the forwarding signature from an annotation and methodMissing (these classes are already extending a base class so I'm sure I can get it to work exactly the way I want with your trick).   I wish there was a way to reward extra rep for this--Maybe I can with a bounty, I need to look into that!

Comment: By the way, what I'm trying to do is create a "class" where each method is runnable from the command line as well as easily callable from code (One class with many small "scripts" in it).  I currently use (List, Map) and parse the CLI arguments in the form "a=b" into the map and place the rest of the argments, in order, into the list--but with this signature it's not obvous how to call it from code, I always have to think about the parameters/order of the list.

Comment: Not sure i got it... you have a class that parses `groovy CliParser.groovy "coolClazz.method1(a, b, c, 90.0)"`?

Comment: Currently I don't use the CliParser but I may do it for this next iteration I'm working on--now I parse it by hand. Each "Script" extends the parent class--the parent class pareses the command line, looks at the first argument, finds a method in the child class named the same way and calls it with the rest of the params. An annotation on each class allows me to print a list of available "scripts" (methods, with documenTation text from the annotation) in any class. It works well now except for the awkward parameters.

Comment: I just came up with `CliParser`, no idea if it exists :-). What if you go for the map solution? You will have to type the parameters name, but the order won't matter...

Comment: There is a CliBuilder in groovy--it's meant to be used with normal scripts and it splits out things like "-x=7" into a map and can print out a usage.  The map solution could work but I'd rather the programatic calling be as natural as possible.  Currently the List,Map solution is a pain because it doesn't help you figure out what you need to pass into a method, instead you have to look through the code to figure it out.  I guess my main goal is to require as little as possible of each script/method.