# Applying default groovy method parameter value when passing null

Tags: groovy, default-value

In Groovy, if I have:

```
def say(msg = 'Hello', name = 'world') {
  "$msg $name!"
}
```

And then call:

```
say() // Hello world!
say("hi") // Hi world!
say(null) // null world!
```

Why is the last one getting interpreted literally as `null` and not applying the default value?  Doesn't this defeat the purpose of default method argument values?  I do get that passing `null` is different from not passing anything w/r/t argument length.

My problem here is that if I now have a method that takes a collection as an argument:

```
def items(Set<String> items = []) {
  new HashSet<>(items)
}
```

This will throw a `NullPointerException` if I call `items(null)` but work fine if I just say `items()`.  In order for this to work right, I have to change the line to be `new HashSet<>(items ?: [])` which, again, seems to defeat the entire purpose of having default method argument values.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Groovy, default parameters generates overloaded methods. Thus, this:

```
def items(Set<String> items = []) {
  new HashSet<>(items)
}
```

Will generate these two methods (I used `javap` to get these values):

```
public java.lang.Object items(java.util.Set<java.lang.String>);
public java.lang.Object items();
```

So when you call `items(null)` you are, in fact, passing some value, and `items(Set)` method will be used.

You can also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393962/groovy-named-parameters-cause-parameter-assignments-to-switch-any-way-around-th/15395306) about default parameters.

Comment: That makes total sense.  Thanks and thanks for the link to the other post.  So is the correct answer then to use the Elvis operator?

Comment: @icfantv and if you dislike the duplication, then use null as the default param and elvis + the value you want to hav.e